# density function of difference of two independent exponential random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent exponential random variables with parameter 1. Find $P(Y\geq X\geq 2)$.

**My attempt:**
Using independence of $X$ and $Y$ we get
$P(Y\geq X\geq 2) = P(Y\geq X) P(X\geq 2) = P(X-Y\leq 0)(1-P(X\leq 2))=...=\frac{1}{2}e^{-2}$

I used the fact that density of $X-Y$ is $f_{X-Y}(z)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-|z|}$
However this turns out to be the wrong answer. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independence does not imply that $P(Y\geq X\geq 2) = P(Y\geq X) P(X\geq 2) $, since $\{Y\ge X\}$ and $\{X\ge2\}$ are not necessarily independent events (just to start, they both are expressed in terms of $X$).

What independence tells you is that the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is
$$f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)=e^{-x}\cdot e^{-y}$$
for $x,y>0$ (and $0$ in other case.)

So the probability you need is
$$\iint_B e^{-(x+y)}\,dA,$$
where $B=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\colon y\ge x \ge 2, x>0, y>0\}$. And this double integral is equivalent to the iterated integral
$$\int_2^\infty \int_2^y e^{-(x+y)}\,dx\,dy.$$